# CasperJSを用いてログイン後にCSVファイルをダウンロードする方法

Tags: javascript, casperjs

CasperJSを用いて http://eoddata.com/ にログインして、csvをダウンロードしたいのですが、タイムアウトエラーになり対策もわからない状態です。

すでにStackoverflowの英語版に質問を投げているのですが、5日ほど反応がもらえずこちらにも質問させて頂きました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160975/how-to-download-a-csv-file-after-login-by-using-casperjs

```
var login_id = "my_user_id";
var login_password = "my_password";

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start("http://eoddata.com/symbols.aspx");
casper.waitForSelector("form input[name = idctl00$cph1$ls1$txtEmail ]", function() {
  this.fillSelectors('form', {
    'input[name = idctl00$cph1$ls1$txtEmail ]' : login_id,
    'input[name = ctl00$cph1$ls1$txtPassword ]' : login_password,
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.download("http://eoddata.com/Data/symbollist.aspx?e=NYSE","nyse.csv");
});

casper.run();
```

どうすれば該当のCSVをダウンロードできるでしょうか？
できればどのような方法でアプローチして解決するかもお願いします。

ブラウザは`casperjs --engine=slimerjs sample.js`と`casperjs sample.js` の両方で動作確認を指定ますがエラーメッセージはどちらも上記のタイムアウトエラーになります。

Comment: 反応がもらえていないというか、「該当する要素が存在しないのだろうからHTMLを確認してみては？」といったことが書かれていませんか？

Comment: すいません、回答がUpdateされているのに気づいていませんでした。教えて頂いている方法をまず試してみます。